# JQuery .autocomplete() select event only triggers when widget loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a `JQuery` `.autocomplete` class bound to an `ASP.NET` form `TextBox` widget.
The relevant code is the following:

```
var _hdnConvenzionato = null;
var _txtConvenzionato = null;

$(function () {
    _hdnConvenzionato = $("input[id$='_hdnConvenzionato']");
    _txtConvenzionato = $("input[id$='_txtConvenzionato']");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetConvenzionati",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var datafromServer = data.d.split("<br />");

            _txtConvenzionato.autocomplete({`enter code here`
                source: datafromServer,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var _data = _txtConvenzionato.val();
                    var _value = null;

                    // calculate _value
    
                    _hdnConvenzionato.val(_value);

                    _hdnConvenzionato.closest("form").submit();
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

The widget in subject is of course the one referenced `_txtConvenzionato`.
The code works fine but the `select` event handler is triggered only when `_txtConvenzionato` lose its focus (I don't know if this's the standard behaviour but it sound strange to me).
Anyway I need it to trigger when a valid hit is found in the items menu.
How can I fix/modify this?
BTW I tried also handling `change` event with similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main issue is that you're trying to use `_txtConvenzionato.val()` to get the selected value. The form element's value is updated *after* the `select` event. Use the `ui.item` from the event arguments to obtain the selected value.

A better approach (with a few more improvements):

```
// general-use "Ajax JSON POST" function, likely to be helpful in other places, too
$.postJSON = function (url, data, success) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: success || null
    });
};

var Convenzionati = $.postJSON("/Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetConvenzionati", {})
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.d.split("<br />");
    })
    .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    });

$(function () {
    Convenzionati.done(function (items) {
        $("input[id$='_txtConvenzionato']").autocomplete({
            source: items,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var _data = ui.item, _value;

                // calculate _value ...
                $("input[id$='_hdnConvenzionato']")
                    .val(_value)
                    .closest("form").submit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Doing the `$.postJSON` request before the `$()` ensures that it starts loading as soon as possible, even before the rest of the page is ready - there is no need to wait for "document ready" to request the autocomplete items. We use the request's `.then()` to transform the response (split at `<br>`) for later use.

Inside the `$()` we only react to the request's `.done`, which will receive the already splitted items, and set up the autocomplete as soon as that's possible. This way your page initializing code and the autocomplete items can load in parallel.

Comment: this's a typo? `ui.item, _value;` or my javascript ignorance is soo deep?! :-)

Comment: @weirdgyn I'm declaring two variables there. `var _data = ui.item, _value;` The first one gets declared and initialized, the second one only gets declared (it will be `undefined` until you give it a value, but it will be correctly scoped as function-local).

Comment: ok.. your hint was obviously correct and the form is working now. The only problem is that `_txtConvenzionato` is not filled with selected data anymore it just show the portion of string I entered.. should select event handler return `true`? To be more precise the partial value is set into `_txtConvenzionato` after the form reloads.

Comment: @weirdgyn No, that should not be necessary. [The documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) says *"Canceling this event prevents the value from being updated"*, so as long as you're not doing that, the value should appear in `_txtConvenzionato` after the select event. Since this is not directly related to your question above, I'd suggest searching for this issue and potentially posting a new question with a minimal repro.

Comment: I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425305/asp-net-form-reload-forced-from-javascript-conflicts-with-jquery-autocomplete-te)..

Comment: @weirdgyn Too bad to see that you didn't take take over the suggestions from my answer...

Comment: @weirdgyn BTW if there is a `select` event, then there is a selected item. Unless `null` is somehow part of the selectable items in your use case (I don't think so) then those null checks are superfluous.

Comment: you are talking about the other question... uhm... I had some issues with `null` values in the past probably due to some other issues .. but you're right..

Comment: uhm... the code you provided seems behave badly. I need to test it some more but it's a lot slower then _mine_ and `autocomplete` is not filtering elements.

Comment: @weirdgyn Ah, I see why that could be. Let me guess, **a)** `/Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetConvenzionati` takes a moment to respond, **b)** it does not support server-side filtering and **c)** the list of values does not change dynamically, but only needs to be loaded once on page load, correct? If so, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @weirdgyn See updated answer. It behaves more or less like your original code did now.

Comment: yes it doesn't support server side filtering and yes the item list doesn't change.