# ASP.NET form reload forced from javascript conflicts with JQuery autocomplete textbox fillup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I defined an ASP.NET form where I have, among many others, the following form elements: a `TextBox`, an `HiddenField` and a `DropDownList` defined like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="_txtData" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="_hdnData" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlData" runat="server" DataSourceID="_sdsData" DataTextField="data" DataValueField="id" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="TUTTI" Value="" Selected="True" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

`_ddlData` is fed from a datasource defined in this way:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="_sdsData" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="
        SELECT 
            id, 
            data
        FROM 
            table_data
        WHERE 
            (@id IS NULL) OR (id = @id)
        ORDER BY targa">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter 
                ControlID="_hdnData" 
                PropertyName="Value" 
                Direction="Input" 
                ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" 
                DbType="Int32" 
                DefaultValue="" 
                Name="id" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

`_hdnData` and `_txtData` are fed trough javascript/JQuery in this way:

[Original code]

```
var _hdnData = null;
var _txtData = null;

$(function () {
    _hdnData = $("input[id$='_hdnData']");
    _txtData = $("input[id$='_txtData']");

    GetData(_txtData , _hdnData );
});

function GetData(source_widget, dest_widget) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetData",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var datafromServer = data.d.split("<br />");

            source_widget.autocomplete({
                source: datafromServer,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var _data = ui.item.value;

                    var _tokens = _data.split("\t");


                    if (_tokens.length < 3)
                        return;

                    var _value = _tokens[_tokens.length - 1].replace(']', '').replace('[', '');

                    dest_widget.val(_value).closest("form").submit();
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

[JQuery optimized code courtesy of @Tomalak]

```
var _hdnData = null;
var _txtData = null;

$.postJSON = function (url, data, success) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: success || null
    });
};

var raw_data = $.postJSON("/Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetData", {})
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.d.split("<br />");
    })
    .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    });

$(function () {
    raw_data.done(function (items) {
        $("input[id$='_txtData']").autocomplete({
            source: items,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var _data = ui.item, _value;

                // calculate _value ...
                $("input[id$='_hdnData ']")
                    .val(_value)
                    .closest("form").submit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When the select event of JQuery `autocomplete` take place the form is submitted and once it *reload* I noticed two major issues:

1. `_txtData` is set to the partial value entered by the user when the select event took place (i.e. not the actual value selected/visibile on the `autocomplete` menu)
2. `_ddlData` values present before select event are merged with new data coming from their datasource.

BTW I don't want, at this time, change `SQLDataSource` or databound components with newer or updated paradigm (like Microsoft Entities Framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a timing issue, like in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423635/18771).

You're submiting the form as part of the `select` event. The selected value is written to the form field by jQuery UI *after* the `select` event, but this code never runs. The `.closest("form").submit()` reloads the page immediately. At this point, the autocomplete field still only contains what the user had typed.

The quick and dirty solution to this is to send the form after a short delay, to give the other events a chance to finish.

```
// ... 
select: function (event, ui) {
    var _data = ui.item,
        _value,
        $form = $(this).closest("form");

    // calculate _value ...

    $("input[id$='_hdnData ']").val(_value);

    setTimeout(function () { $form.submit(); }, 50);
}
```

Comment: what if I need to do just-in-time filtering with autocomplete?

Comment: @weirdgyn Then you would call `$form.submit();` in your autocomplete's success callback.

Comment: I mean I need to filter data along with ajax call . The code you wrote the last time was to get data prior user iteraction with autocomplete bound widget..

Comment: @weirdgyn That doesn't change my answer. The autocomplete widget will have a success callback (in jQuery UI autocomplete it's the [`response` event](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response)). You need to call `$form.submit()` inside that callback, i.e. after you have received the autocomplete response and written the received value to a form field so it can get transmitted with the form POST.

Comment: maybe I got confused by my ingnorance of JQuery but I'm pretty surre that this code does not support server-side filtering (without some reworks). Maybe I'm not been clear in my question. I need to update it in such way. At the moment at page load Ajax call start requesting data from the webservice but given the volume of the data I got an error... I found a solution implementing server side filtering (i.e. changing source: items with an ajax call) but I'm not able to do the same thing on this code.